# jquery how to re-detach a detach on option

Tags: jquery, html-select, detach

I need help concerning following code: http://jsfiddle.net/8PsdE/

```
<SELECT ID="pizzasize" NAME="pizzasize">
<OPTION VALUE="s">small
<OPTION VALUE="m">medium
<OPTION VALUE="l">large
</SELECT>

    $(function() {
   $('#pizzasize > option[value*="m"]').detach();
});
```

How can I add the detached option back again? Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the options you have selected, then you can detach them or do anything else with them using that reference:

```
$(function() {
  var theOptions = $('#pizzasize > option[value*="m"]');
  theOptions.detach();

  // Do other things with theOptions
});
```